# VBA Reference of dropdown selection list

Tags: vba, excel, reference

I have a code that copies all sheets from book 1 to book 2. It copies the sheets several times, so I change the names by adding 001_, 002_ and etc in front of the copied sheets names. All of the sheets have dropdown menues. The problem is that they are referenced (Formulas--> Name Manager) to the previous workbook and they are not working.

There are 5 sheets to be copied and 4 of them are taking the values for the dropdown menues from the sheet TypeLists. This sheet is copied only once, so the code doesn't copy it, if it is already present in Book 2.

Using Record Macro, in changing one of the references, I got this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("003_TDT").Names("List_DataType").RefersToR1C1 = _
    "=TypeLists!R3C14:R5C14"
```

What I did is, I went to Formulas --> Name Manager and changed one of the references from:

='C:\Users\z183464\Desktop[seq_tdt_template.xlsx]TypeLists'!$N$3:$N$5

to:

=TypeLists!$N$3:$N$5

My question is: How can I write a Macro that changes all the references from Book1/TypeLists to Book2/TypeLists ?

Cheers!

Comment: instead of copy pasting..use SAVE AS Macro and delete unwanted stuff (carefully)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code. It iterates through all the defined names and changes its reference to the same value with the undesired part extracted (replaced by "").

This is not a macro, but VBA. You need to insert it in the VBA editor (Alt+F11).

```
Sub replaceNameValues()
    Dim oName As Excel.Name
    For Each oName In ThisWorkbook.Names
        oName.RefersTo = Replace(oName.RefersTo, "C:\Users\z183464\Desktop[seq_tdt_template.xlsx]", "")
    Next
End Sub
```

Regards,